# Setting triple integral boundaries

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, bounds-of-integration

I need to calculate the triple integral ∫∫∫y dxdydz over a region G 
which is given by {|x|<=z, 0<=z<=1, z<=y, x^2+y^2+z^2<=4}

I'm having trouble setting the boundaries for the integral

Would love an explanation, thanks in advance.

Comment: |x|<0?  how does that work?

Comment: A typo, sorry. Corrected now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 5 surfaces that bound your region.

$x = z\\
x = -z\\
y= z\\
z = 0\\
z = 1$

and
$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4$

Here is a rough picture.

[image]
You need to integrate by y first or you else you will need to break this up.

$z \le y \le \sqrt {4-x^2 - z^2}$

And the rest is more direct.

$\int_0^1\int_{-z}^z\int_z^{\sqrt {4-x^2-z^2}} y \ dy \ dx\ dz$

Comment: That is very very helpful. Thank you so much !